# Magento : Original Price is Zero in Sales Order View from programatic order

Tags: magento

I am generating orders from a custom web service called from a mobile app. However when the order is finally generated, I get "Original Price" as Rs0.00 . This is creating a problem since we have third party integrations for invoicing and Shipping.
[image: order from custom web service]

However in the normal course of action when order is generated from website, the Original Price is correct.

[image]

I inspected the sales_flat_order_item table for both these orders, the original_price is indeed 0.00 in the first order, Hence I must be missing something in my code which is not setting the original_price for the orderItem.

Here is the code where the quote is converted to order.

```
    public function placeorder($custid, $Jproduct, $store, $address, $couponCode, $is_create_quote, $transid, $payment_code, $shipping_code, $currency, $message)
{
    $res            = array();
    $quantity_error = array();
    try {
        $quote_data = $this->prepareQuote($custid, $Jproduct, $store, $address, $shipping_code, $couponCode, $currency, 1, 0);
        if ($quote_data["status"] == "error") {
            return $quote_data;
        }
        $quote        = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quote_data['quote_id']);

        $quote        = $this->setQuoteGiftMessage($quote, $message, $custid);
        $quote        = $this->setQuotePayment($quote, $payment_code, $transid);
        $convertQuote = Mage::getSingleton('sales/convert_quote');
        try {
            $order = $convertQuote->addressToOrder($quote->getShippingAddress());
        }
        catch (Exception $Exc) {
            echo $Exc->getMessage();
        }
        $items = $quote->getAllItems();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $orderItem = $convertQuote->itemToOrderItem($item);

            $order->addItem($orderItem);
            }
        try {
            $decode_address = json_decode(base64_decode($address));
            $order->setCustomer_email($decode_address->billing->email);
            $order->setCustomerFirstname($decode_address->billing->firstname)->setCustomerLastname($decode_address->billing->lastname);
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {

        }
        $order->setBillingAddress($convertQuote->addressToOrderAddress($quote->getBillingAddress()));
        $order->setShippingAddress($convertQuote->addressToOrderAddress($quote->getShippingAddress()));
        $order->setPayment($convertQuote->paymentToOrderPayment($quote->getPayment()));
        $order->save();
        $quantity_error         = $this->updateQuantityAfterOrder($Jproduct);
        $res["status"]          = 1;
        $res["id"]              = $order->getId();
        $res["orderid"]         = $order->getIncrementId();
        $res["transid"]         = $order->getPayment()->getTransactionId();
        $res["shipping_method"] = $shipping_code;
        $res["payment_method"]  = $payment_code;
        $res["quantity_error"]  = $quantity_error;
        $order->addStatusHistoryComment("Order was placed using Mobile App")->setIsVisibleOnFront(false)->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
        if ($res["orderid"] > 0 && ($payment_code == "cashondelivery" || $payment_code == "banktransfer" || $payment_code == "free")) {
            $this->ws_sendorderemail($res["orderid"]);
            $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_NEW, true)->save();
            $res["order_status"] = "PENDING_PAYMENT";
        } else {
            $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PENDING_PAYMENT, true)->save();
            $res["order_status"] = "PENDING_PAYMENT";
        }
    }catch (Exception $except) {
        $res["status"]          = 0;
        $res["shipping_method"] = $shipping_code;
        $res["payment_method"]  = $payment_code;
    }

    return $res;
}
```

It would be very helpful if someone points out what I missed. I will edit if any other info is required.

Answer (score 1):

Missing `original_price` indicates that you didn't run `collectTotals()` on the quote yet, try the following:

```
$quote->collectTotals()->save();
$order->save();
```